# C++ Undefined reference to 'Class:Function()'

Tags: c++, teensy, class

I have these files:

- `Project.ino`
- `Sensor.h`
- `Sensor.cpp`
- `IMU/L3G.h`
- `IMU/L3G.cpp`

`Sensor.h`

```
#ifndef Sensor_h
#define Sensor_h

#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "IMU/L3G.h"

#define CUTOFF_FREQ 30
#define FREQ 400


class Sensor {
public:
    Sensor();
    ~Sensor();    
    void Init(void);

pivate:
    L3G gyro;
};
#endif
```

`Sensor.cpp`

```
#include "Sensor.h"

Sensor::Sensor()
{

}
Sensor::~Sensor()
{

}

void Sensor::Init(void)
{
  if (!gyro.init())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to autodetect gyro type!");
    while (1);
  }
  gyro.enableDefault();
}
```

`Project.ino`

```
#include <i2c_t3.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include "Sensor.h"


Sensor sensor = Sensor(); 


void setup() {

  sensor.Init(); 
}
```

I got this error

```
/var/folders/8q/rbt7zf3d28b3k9t6d24k5sn00000gn/T/arduino_build_748953/sketch/Sensor.cpp.o: In function `Sensor::Init()':
/var/folders/8q/rbt7zf3d28b3k9t6d24k5sn00000gn/T/arduino_build_748953/sketch/Sensor.cpp:15: undefined reference to `L3G::init(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
/var/folders/8q/rbt7zf3d28b3k9t6d24k5sn00000gn/T/arduino_build_748953/sketch/Sensor.cpp:20: undefined reference to `L3G::enableDefault()'
```

So, what is wrong?

Comment: `pivate`? typo?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:arduino-uno] and yet the `i2c_t3` is for teensy devices

Comment: @Juraj - once the typo has been fixed, *then* the OP's error is seen.

Comment: What platform are you compiling on (OSX, Windows, Linux)? What version of the IDE are you using? 1.8.5? Where did you source your LMU library from?

Answer (score 2):

As [Juraj rightly points out](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54529/c-undefined-reference-to-classfunction#comment114446_54529), you have a typo, which should give you the following compile time error:

```
In file included from sketch/Sensor.cpp:1:0:
Sensor.h:17: error: 'pivate' does not name a type
 pivate:
 ^
```

Here is the correct code for `Sensor.h`

```
#ifndef Sensor_h
#define Sensor_h

#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "IMU/L3G.h"

#define CUTOFF_FREQ 30
#define FREQ 400


class Sensor {
public:
    Sensor();
    ~Sensor();    
    void Init(void);

private:
    L3G gyro;
};
#endif
```

Using Arduino IDE 1.8.5 with Teensyduino 1.42 with:

- https://github.com/pololu/l3g-arduino
- https://github.com/nox771/i2c_t3

However, once the typo has been corrected, as above, then I too can reproduce your problem (sort of), with these link errors:

```
/var/folders/kp/xv3y9k114yq2_64pf8zwh76h0000gp/T/arduino_build_136680/sketch/Sensor.cpp.o: In function `Sensor::Sensor()':
/var/folders/kp/xv3y9k114yq2_64pf8zwh76h0000gp/T/arduino_build_136680/sketch/Sensor.cpp:3: undefined reference to `L3G::L3G()'
/var/folders/kp/xv3y9k114yq2_64pf8zwh76h0000gp/T/arduino_build_136680/sketch/Sensor.cpp.o: In function `Sensor::Init()':
/var/folders/kp/xv3y9k114yq2_64pf8zwh76h0000gp/T/arduino_build_136680/sketch/Sensor.cpp:14: undefined reference to `L3G::init(L3G::deviceType, L3G::sa0State)'
/var/folders/kp/xv3y9k114yq2_64pf8zwh76h0000gp/T/arduino_build_136680/sketch/Sensor.cpp:19: undefined reference to `L3G::enableDefault()'
/var/folders/kp/xv3y9k114yq2_64pf8zwh76h0000gp/T/arduino_build_136680/core/core.a(main.cpp.o): In function `main':
/Volumes/Home/Users/user/Local_Apps/Arduino/Arduino1.8.5-Teensy.app/Contents/Java/hardware/teensy/avr/cores/teensy3/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `loop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"
 Used: /Volumes/Home/Users/user/Local_Apps/Arduino/Arduino1.8.5-Teensy.app/Contents/Java/hardware/teensy/avr/libraries/Servo
 Not used: /Volumes/Home/Users/user/Local_Apps/Arduino/Arduino1.8.5-Teensy.app/Contents/Java/libraries/Servo
Error compiling for board Teensy 3.5.
```

You are probably getting this error, because you have placed the files `L3G.cpp` and `L3G.h` in a folder called `IMU` in the same folder as your `.ino` file. This causes the undefined error, as, while the IDE sees the declaration in the `L3G.h` file, the IDE can not find the definition in the `L3G.cpp` file.

This is easy to resolve.

If you download the `l3g-arduino-master.zip` file from https://github.com/pololu/l3g-arduino, and from within the Arduino IDE you then add the zipped up L3G library to the Arduino library, using `Sketch ► Include Library ► Add. ZIP Library...` and then change the line

```
#include "IMU/L3G.h"
```

to

```
#include <L3G.h>
```

Then it should compile and link without a problem